# How to get 4th child items from an xml in python

Tags: python, django, xml, dictionary

I have an xml file. It has invoice informations. I'm trying to save them to my mysql database. First I'm getting invoice's header informations and save them to a django model. Then trying to get the product part. But I coldn't get it done.

here is my sample xml

```html
<SIPARISLER>
<SIPARIS>
<SIPARIS_NO>YT3949031</SIPARIS_NO>
<PAZARYERI_KARGOKODU/>
<CariHesapKodu>YT2099</CariHesapKodu>
<CariHesapOzelKodu>YT</CariHesapOzelKodu>
<POSTA>ayse@icir.com</POSTA>
<TARIH>2016-06-28</TARIH>
<sipariszaman>08:56:58</sipariszaman>
<ISKONTO>0</ISKONTO>
<NET_TOPLAM>62.33</NET_TOPLAM>
<TeslimAlici>Ayydın</TeslimAlici>
<TeslimAdresi>Arvat Atayolu Cad. ÖztaşrnLogipark a - anbul</TeslimAdresi>
<TeslimTelefon>0506-0624914</TeslimTelefon>
<teslimsekli>KR</teslimsekli>
<tasiyicifirma>MNG</tasiyicifirma>
<teslimkod1/>
<teslimkod4/>
<teslimil>İstanbul</teslimil>
<teslimilce>Tuzla</teslimilce>
<faturaalici/>
<faturaAdresi>İncir Elektrizm. A.Ş. rnYahya Kemal Mah. Şair Plaza Kağıthane ul</faturaAdresi>
<faturaTelefon>05014</faturaTelefon>
<faturavergino>478034</faturavergino>
<faturavergidairesi>Zincirlikuyu</faturavergidairesi>
<faturail>İstanbul</faturail>
<faturailce>Kağıthane</faturailce>
<kargokodu>YT986031</kargokodu>
<ODEME_SEKLI>Havale/ EFT</ODEME_SEKLI>
<kargo_odemesi>Alıcı Öder</kargo_odemesi>
// KARGO ÖDEME BİLGİSİ
<SATIRLAR>
<SATIR>
<KOD>U66YT0554P</KOD>
<VARKOD>VARYAN-KODU-GELECEK</VARKOD>
<MIKTAR>1</MIKTAR>
<BIRIM>Ad.</BIRIM>
<FIYAT>11.16</FIYAT>
<KDV>18</KDV>
</SATIR>
<SATIR>
<KOD>N5YT0352</KOD>
<VARKOD>VARYAN-KODU-GELECEK</VARKOD>
<MIKTAR>2</MIKTAR>
<BIRIM>Ad.</BIRIM>
<FIYAT>16.74</FIYAT>
<KDV>18</KDV>
</SATIR>
<SATIR>
<KOD>I19YT0051</KOD>
<VARKOD>VARYAN-KODU-GELECEK</VARKOD>
<MIKTAR>1</MIKTAR>
<BIRIM>Ad.</BIRIM>
<FIYAT>2.33</FIYAT>
<KDV>18</KDV>
</SATIR>
<SATIR>
<KOD>X73YT3148</KOD>
<VARKOD>VARYAN-KODU-GELECEK</VARKOD>
<MIKTAR>3</MIKTAR>
<BIRIM>Ad.</BIRIM>
<FIYAT>5.12</FIYAT>
<KDV>8</KDV>
</SATIR>
<SATIR>
<KOD>MNG</KOD>
<VARKOD>VARYAN-KODU-GELECEK</VARKOD>
<MIKTAR>1</MIKTAR>
<BIRIM>Ad.</BIRIM>
<FIYAT>0.00</FIYAT>
<KDV>18</KDV>
</SATIR>
</SATIRLAR>
</SIPARIS>
</SIPARISLER>
```

my views for django:

```html
    try:
        response = requests.get(URL)
        if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            print("XML'i Çekemedik")
        veri = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
        print("veri dict edildi")
        siparisler = veri['SIPARISLER']['SIPARIS']
        for siparis in siparisler:
            siparis_no = siparis['SIPARIS_NO']
            print("!", siparis_no, " kaydı kontrol ediliyor..")
            qs = Siparisler.objects.filter(siparis_no=siparis_no)
            exists = qs.exists()
            if not exists:
                print("!", siparis_no, " kayıt ediliyor..")
                try:
                    pazar_yeri_kargo_kodu = siparis['PAZARYERI_KARGOKODU']
                    siparis_tarih = siparis['TARIH']
                    siparis_saat = siparis['sipariszaman']
                    iskonto = siparis['ISKONTO']
                    net_toplam = siparis['NET_TOPLAM']
                    cari_hesap_kodu = siparis['CariHesapKodu']
                    cari_hesap_ozel_kodu = siparis['CariHesapOzelKodu']
                    siparis_posta = siparis['POSTA']
                    teslim_alici = siparis['TeslimAlici']
                    teslim_adresi = siparis['TeslimAdresi']
                    teslim_telefon = siparis['TeslimTelefon']
                    teslim_sekli = siparis['teslimsekli']
                    teslim_ilce = siparis['teslimilce']
                    teslim_firma = siparis['tasiyicifirma_adi']
                    teslim_kod1 = siparis['teslimkod1']
                    teslim_kod4 = siparis['teslimkod4']
                    teslim_il = siparis['teslimil']
                    fatura_alici = siparis['faturaalici']
                    fatura_adresi = siparis['faturaAdresi']
                    fatura_telefon = siparis['faturaTelefon']
                    fatura_vergino = siparis['faturavergino']
                    fatura_vergidairesi = siparis['faturavergidairesi']
                    fatura_il = siparis['faturail']
                    fatura_ilce = siparis['faturailce']
                    kargo_kodu = siparis['kargokodu']
                    odeme_sekli = siparis['kargo_odemesi_adi']
                    yenisiparis = Siparisler(siparis_no=siparis_no, pazar_yeri_kargo_kodu=pazar_yeri_kargo_kodu, siparis_tarih=siparis_tarih, siparis_saat=siparis_saat, iskonto=iskonto, net_toplam=net_toplam, cari_hesap_kodu=cari_hesap_kodu, cari_hesap_ozel_kodu=cari_hesap_ozel_kodu, siparis_posta=siparis_posta, teslim_alici=teslim_alici, teslim_adresi=teslim_adresi, teslim_telefon=teslim_telefon,teslim_sekli=teslim_sekli,teslim_ilce=teslim_ilce,teslim_firma=teslim_firma,teslim_kod1=teslim_kod1,teslim_kod4=teslim_kod4,teslim_il=teslim_il,fatura_alici=fatura_alici,fatura_adresi=fatura_adresi,fatura_telefon=fatura_telefon,fatura_vergino=fatura_vergino,fatura_vergidairesi=fatura_vergidairesi,fatura_il=fatura_il,fatura_ilce=fatura_ilce,kargo_kodu=kargo_kodu,odeme_sekli=odeme_sekli)
                    yenisiparis.save()
                    print("!", siparis_no, " kayıt edildi..")
                except:
                    print("Sipariş kaydedilirken bir hata oluştu")

                satirlarx = siparis['SATIRLAR']['SATIR']
                print(satirlarx)

                for sat in satirlarx:
                    fatura_adi = sat['FATURA_ADI']
                    print(fatura_adi)


            else:
                print("!", siparis_no, " kayıtlı..")








    except:
        print("XML Cekerken Hata Oldu" , sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

and I'm getting an errro like this:

```html
...

! 175550367  kayıtlı..
! 175551445  kaydı kontrol ediliyor..
! 175551445  kayıtlı..
! 175552540  kaydı kontrol ediliyor..
! 175552540  kayıt ediliyor..
! 175552540  kayıt edildi..
OrderedDict([('URUNKODU', 'INC90128'), ('KOD', 'INC90128'), ('VARKOD', None), ('BARCODE', '8681511090128'), ('URUNADI', 'Incia Kaş ve Kirpik Güçlendirici Doğal Serum 10 ml'), ('FATURA_ADI', 'Kaş Ve Kirpik güçlendirici Doğal Serum 10 ml 8681511090128, one size'), ('SECENEK_DEGERI', None), ('FIYAT', ['50.49', '50.49']), ('MIKTAR', '1'), ('BIRIM', 'Ad.'), ('KDV', '18')])
XML Cekerken Hata Oldu <class 'TypeError'>
```

Comment: could you identify what equivalent is the word product in your xml? helpful for some of us who are not familiar with the language

Comment: And kindly post ur expected output as well.

Comment: <SATIR> is eauivalent for product. For example I want "product_code = <KOD>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ElementTree for processing XML response

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

response = requests.get(URL)
        if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            print("XML'i Çekemedik")
root = ET.fromstring(response)
```

After that, you can use indexing to read a particular attribute. For example, to read first element under root you can write root[0]. You can read [More on ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) here.

Comment: "root = ET.fromstring(response.content)" just a little correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [xml etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module, with [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to get the data you need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#wrapped the text above in a variable named data
#if reading from a file, 
#you can use this :
#root = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(data)

#this looks for SATIR, followed by KOD
#and returns the text embedded
for entry in root.findall(".//SATIR/KOD"):
    print(entry.text)

U66YT0554P
N5YT0352
I19YT0051
X73YT3148
MNG
```